# How can I filter html file content with java regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, xml

With java I can download a webpage into the txt file.Now I want to read values from this txt file by regular expression.The below is the small part of the real html.

```
<div>
   <input id="_NAME" value="/John/" />
   <input id="_LASTNAME" value="/BOND/"/>
   <input id="_Class"   value="5" />
</div>
```

I just want to read values according to id (_Name and _LASTNAME)?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I use the XML parser but the website structure really bad designed

Comment: Use a HTML parser, e.g. JSoup. As long as the part you want looks as good as what you have shown above (and the tag brackets `<>` are closed properly), it should be parsable.

Comment: The part I write is parsable but the webpage is bad structured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the HTML file is usable when browsing, it should be parsable by Jsoup. Since you are only querying attributes of `input` element, you don't really have to worry about the structure of the resulting DOM.

Sample code, using your example of HTML, with a bunch of bad HTML tag in front:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class SO27938637 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div><span><div><b>sdf</span>dsf<i>sdfdsfsdfds<span></div><div>\n    <input id=\"_NAME\" value=\"/John/\" />\n   <input id=\"_LASTNAME\" value=\"/BOND/\"/>\n   <input id=\"_Class\"   value=\"5\" /></div>");
        Elements inputElement = doc.select("input");

        for (Element e: inputElement) {
            System.out.println(e.attr("id") + ": " + e.attr("value"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
_NAME: /John/
_LASTNAME: /BOND/
_Class: 5
```

Comment: question was using regex, but it works like a charm :)